# Mr. G.P.K.'s questions

Tags: tag-removed

> **WARNING**: An acquaintance of mine, Mr.Goosepond Prhklstr Kratchinabritchisitch, has requested permission to post  his questions under my username. When I asked him why he didn't do it under his own name, he gave me a convoluted answer of which I didn't understand a word (as usual with him). So, as a pure courtesy, I'm letting him ask his questions but I want to emphasize  that I do not in the least endorse anything he  might say. As a precaution I'm making his post community wiki, but I confess that I'm still more than a little apprehensive...   **Georges Elencwajg**

**Mr. Goosepond Prhklstr Kratchinabritchisitch's questions:**

1) Why do you people continually talk of "elliptic curves"? They should just be called ellipses ( a special sort of comics) and are very easy to draw with a piece of string (I suppose that's what is nowadays bombastically called "string theory"). You can also easily study them with analytic geometry: their equation is simply $\frac {a^2}{x^2}+ \frac {b^2}{y^2}=1$.

2) Why do you hide *all* posts on descriptive geometry, compilation of seven decimal logarithmic tables, remarkable points of a triangle, etc: in other words the hard core of Mathematics?

3) Conversely, why so many posts on categories? Don't you people understand that they are just a fad, like the yo-yo, the hula-hoop or the computer?

4) I see many people refer to some GAGA article by a Jean-Paul Serre. Why don't grown-ups here tell this teenager to stop mentioning extravagant pop-singers ? What the FAC is coming next?

5) Why do people always talk of Dedekind's character? What's wrong with this guy?

6) I saw mentions of the Tango bundle and of the Serre twist (him again!) What's coming next: the Cauchie boogie-woogie, the Nagata salsa or the Cartan can-can ?

7) How come I couldn't find any financial statement  in *Forbes* or the *Wall Street Journal* on a multinational like MO and the moguls running  it? Why do investors (I'm talking to you, Warren Buffett!) tolerate this? Take the C.E.O, Mr. Geraschenko, for example:  I couldn't  even find out under which flag his yacht sails.

8) Why are you so afraid of acknowledging the [top specialists in mathematics ?](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/oia/gv/parasol/referee-form.sample.pdf)

**G.P. Kratchinabritchisitch**

Comment: It is very kind of you that you agreed just today to this request.

Comment: I don't think this belongs here (not even today); downvotes are not mine, however.

Comment: Nice try, but not very funny (IMHO). 

Comment: +1. Once a year, let's not take ourselves too seriously :-) 

Comment: In my opinion GPK makes a rational point on elliptic curves.

Comment: I'm downvoting because a) this certainly doesn't match the criteria for acceptable posts, and b) this comes across as mocking a certain class of poster, which I think is inappropriate.

Comment: At least the intent was not misplaced; if you could not pull out at least half a smile from this post, then I apologize on the poster's behalf ;-)

Comment: +1, definitely a good laugh :)

Comment: This makes more sense to me than Glenn Beck, and therefore does not so much cheer me as plunge me into a slough of despond...

Answer (score 10):

Happy April Fool's?

Comment: I don't think anyone could possibly believe this is a real person...but I do wonder if the name has any hidden meaning. "chinabritchi" suggests a half Chinese/British person to me.

Comment: It is from James Joyce's "Ulysses" (not that I knew, I found out from google).